# SDL2 does not see joystick, but OS does

Tags: ubuntu, sdl-2, hid, joystick, input-devices

I am using *Ubuntu 18.0.4.4 LTS* with a home-brew Arduino-based USB joystick attached.

The OS sees the device at both `/dev/input/js0` and `/dev/input/event5` and jstest works with it:

```
$ jstest /dev/input/js0 
Driver version is 2.1.0.
Joystick (Arduino LLC Arduino Micro) has 6 axes (X, Y, Z, Rx, Ry, Rz)
and 0 buttons ().
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Axes:  0:     0  1:     0  2:     0  3:     0  4:     0  5:     0 ^C
```

evtest also works, as root:

```
$ sudo evtest /dev/input/event5 
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x2341 product 0x8037 version 0x101
Input device name: "Arduino LLC Arduino Micro"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value      0
      Min     -100
      Max      100
      Flat      12
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value      0
      Min     -100
      Max      100
      Flat      12
    Event code 2 (ABS_Z)
      Value      0
      Min     -100
      Max      100
      Flat      12
    Event code 3 (ABS_RX)
      Value      0
      Min     -100
      Max      100
      Flat      12
    Event code 4 (ABS_RY)
      Value      0
      Min     -100
      Max      100
      Flat      12
    Event code 5 (ABS_RZ)
      Value      0
      Min     -100
      Max      100
      Flat      12
```

Yet, SDL2's `SDL_NumJoysticks()` always returns 0, despite initializing SDL2 with joystick and gamepad support:

```
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK | SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER | SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_AUDIO );
```

Why can't [SDL2](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryJoystick) not use a working /dev/input/js0 device on Ubuntu?

Comment: Self-built SDL2 or binaries from Ubuntu's repos?

Comment: These were from Ubuntu repo.

Comment: @Bram what are your `/dev/input/event*` permissions? I suppose you need at least read permissions (and probably write too if you have force feedback). Check output of `strace -e file ./your_test_program`.

Comment: @keltar When running as root, the joystick is found. If you write it up, I will mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL2 [uses](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/355a4f94a782/src/joystick/linux/SDL_sysjoystick.c#l26) `/dev/input/event*` device files to access joysticks/gamepads, so you need read (and in some cases write) permissions for that files. Most linux distros use special user group for that files, e.g. `input` group on debian or gentoo; check what's your permissions are and make your user member of appropriate group (and re-login after that).

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with pygame and a raspberry Pi 4. Since pygame hides a lot of error messages it took me quite a long time to find the culprit. The solution proposed by @keltar worked for me. For the sake of completeness I share the command:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG input username
```